# sql server html in textbox

Tags: javascript, html, sql, sql-server

I have the folowing code in a MSSQL RDL textbox.

```html
="<a href='"& Fields!URL.Value & "' target='_blank' rel='external'>Print Link</a>"
```

The textbox properties are set to HTML.
However when I view the report in the report server the

```html
target='_blank'
```

and

```html
rel='external'
```

don't show up, instead it gets a

```html
target='_top'
```

I also tried javascript to open the window for example:

```html
="<a href='javascript:window.open("& Fields!URL.Value & "');>Print Link</a>"
```

But that presents problems when I export to pdf and it also doesn't work in the report preview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead... Put this in the Go To URL Action

```
="javascript:void(window.open('"+ Fields!URL.Value + "','_blank'))"
```

http://bidn.com/Blogs/userid/10/SSRS-Action-to-Open-a-URL-in-a-New-Window

Comment: I can't use that because it needs to set the target of the link. I have tried that and the target opens the window in the same window as the one I used.

Comment: Updated answer.